# Can 3D printed food be considered halal?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, food

Today we live in a world where it is possible to print edible vegetables and meat for consumption. Although still in it's infancy, it is predicted in the next 20-30 years it will be as ubiquitous as fast food in the western world.

Do we have any ijtehad among the Ulema at the moment whether meat derived from such printing techniques using synthetic meat is permissible to eaten or not?

**Edit:**
If you’re curious about how these meals are made, 3D printed food is a leap from conventional 3D printing. You build up an object on a build plate, layer-by-layer, by extruding material from a heated nozzle. Only this time the object in question isn’t made from molten plastic but from recognizable foodstuffs like chocolate, pasta, vegetables, and even meat.

The recipes are preprogrammed, and the raw ingredients are pureed and blended into a semi-liquid form so that they can be loaded into food-safe syringes or capsules, and then extruded through the print-head. Most of these dishes are ready to eat straight from the printer, but others — like the meat and bread preparations — will require further steps like baking or grilling in an oven.

Comment: It would depend on whether the base material is halal. I don't see how 3d printing would make a difference on the ruling?

Comment: Most of the base materials are made in the lab using synthetic organic chemistry. Currently, it is relatively easy to develop  low-molecular-weight compounds, such as vitamins and amino acids but not high-molecular-weight compounds, like proteins (mainly for meat). So if we assume the fiqh of base ingredients would apply, I guess the question would be is synthetically developed meat fine to consume?