# Lab grown meat halal/haram?

Tags: halal-haram, meat

Inshallah brothers and sisters

I work inside a laboratory developing lab grown meats. I want to know if the consumption (and by extension, production) is halal or haram.

For context, I have refrained from trying this meat in case it is Haram (better to be halal than sorry).

The process: We found a chicken who recently had shed a feather, and using science methods we extract the DNA and grow the muscle cells in a big glass bottle, then we filter cells from the growing liquid to make the meat.

The chicken is currently alive, so I am thinking this is halal, but need guidance. However once the chicken dies does it become haram? Do we still have to perform ritual on the chicken, what if they run away?

One of my Muslim friends suggested we are playing God, but we grow Turkeys so big that they cannot physically have sex anymore, but kill them in halal way then it's halal, is this not natural, is it natural that we put chickens in factory farms, factory farms are not designed by God.

Sorry for the long post.
Alhamdulillah

Comment: Is there bloodflow in the artificial tissue?

Comment: There is no heart to pump blood, but there is blood vessels. Like a car without the engine.

Comment: Similar Question: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/56087/can-3d-printed-food-be-considered-halal